# Solve $tx\dot{x}=x^2-1$. I am pretty confused here.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Solve $tx\dot{x}=x^2-1$.

What I did so far is:

$$\dot{x}={x^2-1\over xt}\Rightarrow {dx\over dt}={x^2-1\over xt} \Rightarrow {dx}={x^2-1\over xt}dt$$ 
meaning 
$$\int_{x(t_0)}^{x(t)}1=\int_{t_0}^{t}{x^2-1\over xt}dt=\int_{t_0}^{t}{x^2\over xt}dt-{1\over x}\int_{t_0}^{t}{1\over t}dt=\int_{t_0}^{t}{x\over t}dt-{1\over x}\int_{t_0}^{t}{1\over t}dt$$ 
(That's the part where I think I really misused $x$ and integration laws, although I had no other options). I get: 
$$x=x\ln{|t|}-{1\over x}\ln{|t|}.$$ 
Differentiating with respect to $t$ it gets: $$\dot{x}={x\over t}-{1\over xt}$$ and multiplying both sides by $tx$ bring the equation to the starting position. I still feel I conducted unprofessionally and would really appreciate remarks regarding how okay my perception and methods are.

Comment: Perhaps I should have left x within the $\ln$ function input.

Comment: If you multiply $\dot{x} = 1 - \dfrac 1{xt}$ by $tx$ you should have $tx - 1$, not $x^2 - 1$

Comment: I edited it. Thank you for bringing that to my attention.

Comment: Your integral may not contain both $x$ and $t$, because $x$ is an unknown function of $t$, that you are not allowed to treat like a constant.

Comment: You can not integrate $\int\frac {x(t)}t\,dt$ without knowing what $x(t)$ is, so your form of integration is self-defeating. Since $x(t)$ is almost surely not a constant, you can not extract it from the integral, $\int \frac1{tx(t)}dt=\frac1{x(t)}\int\frac1tdt$ is just wrong.

Comment: You just set my entire initial comprehension of this theory in place. Thank you all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
tx\cdot \dot{x} &= x^2 - 1 \\
tx \cdot \dfrac {dx}{dt} &= x^2 -1 \\
\dfrac {x}{x^2 - 1} dx &= \dfrac 1{t} dt
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

*Now* try integrating and see if that helps.

Comment: In the integral, what values should I use at the ends? $x(t)$ and $x(t_0)$? Or $x$ and $x_0$?
$x_0$ doesn't seem to mean anything...

Comment: You can use indefinite integration, you just have to add one integration constant that is then computed via initial values.

Answer (score 2):

Substitute $y=x^2$ to find
$$
t\dot y=2(y-1)
$$

Comment: Thank you for your offer. Does that mean I was wrong to leave $x^2$ as is?

Comment: You will have to use substitution (directly or implicitly) somewhere. Either from the start like here or by substitution in the integral as appears in the other answer. There probably using $u=x^2-1$.

Answer (score 2):

There are unfortunately several mistakes here, but at the heart of them all is the perception that you can take $x$ as a constant when you're 'working with' $t$.  Unfortunately, since $x$ is a function of $t$, this isn't going to work out for you.  For a simpler example of the fallacy with this, consider the differential equation $\dot{x}=tx$; the solution of this is $x=Ce^{(t^2/2)}$ (use the chain rule) but your method would give $dx=tx\ dt$, $\int(1)\ dx=\int tx\ dt$, and then $x=\frac{t^2}{2}x+C$, which is clearly wrong.  Instead, as others have noted you need to separate the variables fully; you can't treat $x$ as a variable in one place and a constant in another.

The same mistake creeps in when you try to check your solution, which is why it looks on the surface like things check out; the derivative with respect to $t$ of, e.g., $x\ln |t|$ *isn't* $\frac xt$, because $x$ is still a function of $t$.  Instead, the best you can say not knowing what function of $t$ $x$ represents is $\dfrac{d}{dt} x\ln t=\left(\dfrac{d}{dt}x\right)\ln t+x\left(\dfrac{d}{dt}\ln t\right)$ $= \dot{x}\ln t+\dfrac xt$.